# php authentication best practice...?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I have a simple login page that checks credentials against database and then every page includes `auth.php` that verifies `$_SESSION['logged']` is set and that session isn't expired.

Problem is that every page also includes another page `tab.php` (something like a menu), which I also need to restrict access to, but including `auth.php` inside `tab.php` makes the inclusion occur twice. If I don't include the `auth.php` in `tab.php`, though, anyone can access `tab.php` directly bypassing authentication check and possibly retrieve private information.

Any best practice to solve this situation?

EDIT:

And I forgot to ask, but what path you use to make it relative to site root? As both `auth.php` and `tab.php` are in folder and the `index.php` which includes `tab.php` is in root - the include function gives an error for either `index.php` or `tab.php` according to what path I use (`'./includes/auth.php'` OR `'./auth.php'`) - If you know what I mean. I tried '/includes/auth.php' but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "anyone could access tab.php"? Do you mean that if they know the path to the file they could go look at it by typing it manually?

Comment: So you want to make sure, that auth.php must be included but you don't want to include it twice?

Comment: Don't you just need: `include_once()`?

Comment: You surely have a way of telling if the user is actually logged in, don't you? Why not use that to find out in `tab.php` if the user is authorized to see the menu?

Comment: Gazillion: Yes (as I am unsure how hard it is to scan site's structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include_once` and `require_once` will definitely assure that you don't have the same file included more than once (at the same time make sure you're authenticated).

What I would do, however, is add your includes in a "include" folder and forbid access - to people who would type in the path manually - through an htaccess file. This way you could keep your includes in one place (whatever your header includes might look like) and keep your include files clean and still out of reach. If you were to do this you'd only have to do what Jan. mentioned in the answer above and check if your `$_SESSION['logged']` is set (and whatever other checks you need)

Comment: This seems like a perfect idea to me (for I already have my include files in a separate folder), but the concept is new to me. Do you still have to include `$_SESSION['logged']` check in included files(`tab.php` and others) when you restrict access to that folder at all?

Comment: Well I don't really know how your site works. In this case I suppose you wouldn't really need it, but I usually have different menus depending the type of user (admin, moderator, vanilla user). So in this case, instead of checking whether they are really authenticated I'd check what kind of user and display the correct tabs.

Comment: My point was to restrict access to that `tab.php` file which in itself will never be loaded in browser alone (it doesn't even contain styles, only text) - in case someone types the file path manually. Also I just realized that by checking for `$_SESSION` you'd have to also initialize `session_start();` inside the `tab.php` and if you would later include this page inside `index.php`, you get double session initialization, if I get it right.

Comment: Well then, the .htaccess file within your "includes" folder will do that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`include_once`](http://php.net/include_once) instead of [`include`](http://php.net/include) in your files (or `require_once` and `require`).  This will insure that your `auth.php` file will only be included once in the lifetime of the script.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wanted to make sure if what I am actually doing is considered best practice or there are other ways of limiting access to files included in other files, if you follow me.

Comment: Still, you're calling the authentication method twice, which is not needed when you write to the session on authentication success. It's sufficient to check for the correct session value in tab.php and draw an error, if it's not available.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that defeats the whole point of having this check in separate file. For example if I were to change session time limit I'd have to change it in `auth.php` as well as in the `tab.php` (and other files that are being included - the `auth.php` consists of `$_SESSION` check and `$_SESSION` time limit

Answer (score 0):

Just check in tab.php if the session is initialized and $_SESSION['logged'] is true. This will work fine, if auth.php is loaded first.

Comment: And otherwise will return an error or warning and fill your logs with uunnecessary messages

Comment: It will not. Just code smart: `if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || !$_SESSION['logged']) { die('Access not granted'); }`

Comment: Anyway this is a wobbly solution, because he'd have to add this code to any file he might be using later. What if he changes the session namespace? He'd have to adapt that to every file he's using your solution in. require_once is better I guess

Comment: Well... The same applies to include_once or require_once - it must be in all available file. The difference is, that you have no need to insert any further application routines and init scripts with my approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using `require_once("auth.php");`? This makes sure, that auth.php is included (otherwise application will stop) but only includes the file **once** which seems to be your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try include_once(). See ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php )