# Restrict access to directory, using .htaccess, if some page returns 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I am trying to deny access to an entire directory, unless a file (where ever it may be) returns a 200 status. This needs to be written in my .htaccess file. I am aware this is not valid .htaccess syntax, except for the `deny from all` part, I am just demonstrating my concept.

```
if(external-page.php returns anything but 200 header)
{
    # deny the current directory
    deny from all
}
```

The **external-page.php** will be running a script that checks whether a user has valid credentials. If they do, it will load the page with a 200 status. If they are not a valid user it will return a 404 status.

The .htaccess file is located in the directory I want to deny, however, the script I want to check the status of is not in that directory.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Since there seems to be some confusion. I have listed my directory structure below:

```
DIRECTORY_A/
    DIRECTORY_B/
        .HTACESS
        FILE_1.PHP
        FILE_2.PHP
        FILE_3.PHP
    FILE_A.PHP
```

Based on this directory structure what I am trying to do is this... If `FILE_A.PHP` returns 404 (or it can return anything, as long as I can check it). Then I want to deny all access to `DIRECTORY_B`. If `FILE_A.PHP` returns 200 (or true, or whatever I can check) then I want to allow access to `DIRECTORY_B`

If using .htaccess is not the best way to accomplish this, then I am open to another method. However, I am restricted from putting code in `FILE_1.PHP` and `FILE_2.PHP` and `FILE_1.PHP`... which is why I want to restrict access to the entire `DIRECTORY_B` directory.

Comment: Do you want 404 or 200... ?

Comment: I would prefer to check for 200 status, but I can check for 404 too. Either one is fine.

Comment: why?!! what's the use of this? if files in that directory are being transferred through the script your deny from all won't help you do anything, if not then you're actually denying access from all users including valid ones.

Comment: Is what you mean that you want to stop people from viewing the files in your directory?

Comment: @meewoK yes... only if the script I am checking outside that directory returns a 404 status

Comment: @ahmad No it would not. The script I am checking is OUTSIDE that directory. The reason I need to do it this way is because I need to deny access to a bunch of classes based on if a WordPress user is logged in. Everything I have tried, inside the class, breaks the class.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information... your using include? your using HTTP get? Your using AJAX? The classes are within PHP files? They are in another directory? I seem to be getting the following feeling:
You want to check the return code a user gets for another address and based on that (which is determined by if he is logged in) allow or deny him. Essentially you want a login mechanism for the whole site.

Comment: @meewoK I have updated my question. Hopefully that gives more insight. But like you said in your last sentence, that is what I am looking to do.

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems to be your after an authentication script actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this kind of dependency .htaccess is not a script

Comment: I ended up having to use PHP

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do what you want is to have an authentication php script that is included in all your PHP files and checks for a session.
When you include one PHP file in another, it is executed.

So, FILE_A.php would have authentication code, and be included by FILE_1.php, FILE-2.php, FILE_3.php.

You don't need .htaccess as you can set the header (e.g. forbidden) directly from PHP.

- e.g. header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');

see:

- [php authentication best practice...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966848/php-authentication-best-practice)
- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
- http://dhost.info/forums/index.php?topic=11676.0

Just for fun though you could do the following:

- Do the authentication in FILE_A.php and set the header depending on what is the result.
- Include FILE_A.PHP from Other php files.
- Use var_dump(http_response_code()) in the other files to detect the header set by FILE_A.php and display a different output.

Comment: This helped me get 1 step closer! Still working on it as some of the files are conflicting with the script I am using.

Comment: I am using this... http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com/ Everything I place in the class cause some sort of error.